# Strange behavior of Swift

Tags: swift

While playing around with Swift I came across the following scenario:

```
let testVar: String = "random string"
var myVar: Int! = 0
myVar = Int(testVar)
print("myVar = \(myVar)")
```

Output:-

> myVar = nil

Since I have used `!` mark before `myVar`, isn't it supposed to contain non-nil values all the time?
How come `myVar` is `nil`?
Here is the screenshot of my playground code:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: then what is your expectation. should playground going to be crashed?

Comment: Tried the same code in a xcode project  and the output remains same. Was expecting a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '!' indicates forced unwrapping of an optional.  However it's type is still optional and therefore can be nil.

(You're just telling the compiler that you guarantee it **won't** become nil.)

A line like...

```
let v: Int = myVar
```

...at the end of your code will get you the crash you expect.

---

Another example is the way outlets are handled.  They are typically defined such as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
```

Before `viewDidLoad` is called, it is nil.  Again, the '!' is just a promise to the compiler that it won't be used until it contains a valid reference.

Comment: Thanks @Phillip. Your example cleared my doubt. Just to add to your answer, found this in Apple's official documentation -
“If an implicitly unwrapped optional is nil and you try to access its wrapped value, you’ll trigger a runtime error. The result is exactly the same as if you place an exclamation mark after a normal optional that does not contain a value.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1).” iBooks. https://itun.es/in/jEUH0.l"

Answer (score 0):

I think it is becuuse you are converting your `testVar` to an `int` when it is a `string`. Since `myVar`is unwrapped it may be defaulting to nil